# how to convert object dtype to inter dtype in pandas?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, casting

i have a problem to change the object dtype of a column to integer dtype in a dataframe.

I have a dataframe column with a datatype "object"  syntax as  "136.89" like this, if i tried to change its's datatype to int64 or float64 by astype() method it was raising a
`ValueError: could not convert string to float: '.'`

if i tried to use to_numeric() method the values are rounding like 13689, how would i get 136 or 137 in integer format, please help and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use `df.astype(float).astype(int)`

```
import pandas as pd

data = [
    ['123.45', '456'],
    ['234.56', '789']
]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['a', 'b'])
assert (df.dtypes == object).all()

df2 = df.astype(float).astype(int)
assert (df2.dtypes == int).all()

print(df2)
```

```
     a    b
0  123  456
1  234  789
```

That truncates the floats to remove the fractional part.  If you want to round to the nearest integer, use `round()`:

```
df3 = df.astype(float).round().astype(int)
print(df3)
```

```
     a    b
0  123  456
1  235  789
```